# Reverse Polish Notation with power

Tags: arithmetic, polish-notation

Perhaps I'm just not understanding RPN correctly, but whenever I translate something like

`2^2^3` then I get `22^3^`

But if I try to execute that it's wrong! Because that will result in 64 (4^3), but what I need it to do is result in 256 (2^8)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `2 2 3 ^ ^`, because exponentiation is normally understood from right to left. That is, something like `2^2^3` means `2^(2^3)`, not `(2^2)^3`.  So when you convert to RPN that's how you have to convert it.

Comment: RIGHT! Because the two rules are IF 1) operator precedence is greater OR 2) operator precedence is equal AND left associative THEN push.